# Find longest sublist with given average in sorted doubly linked list in O(n)

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

Given an number and a sorted doubly linked list (with data as integers), I have to find the longest sublist which average is the given number in O(n).
How would you go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you find the cumulative sums of all the indexes. Say this is an array, `cumsum[1..n]`

Now, start with two pointers, one pointing at the first node and one at the last node. Compute average of this range as `(cumsum[last]-cumsum[first])/(last-first+1)`. If this is larger than the target average (say `k`), then move the back pointer inwards, since that will always reduce the average (since it is sorted). Likewise, if `avg < k`, move the front pointer forward. This way you'll either end up with a range with average k if it exists, or realize that such a k doesn't exist if front and back pointers cross. Since we move at least one of the pointers in every step, this is O(n).